# How to make a link open in new tab as well as redirect in current

Tags: javascript, html

So, I need to make it so if the user is on mysite.com/cat and they click something, then in the mysite.com/cat tab, they are redirected to mysite.com/dog AND a link is opened in a new tab. I tried this: `<a href="dog.html" target="_self" onclick="window.open('cat.html');">Click</a>` which kind of worked, but it would like... make it all weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a href="#" target="_self" onclick="RedirectUrl()">Click</a> 
<script>
    
    function RedirectUrl(){    
       window.location.href ="yourUrl";
    }
    <script>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that but the 2nd link isn't opening, its redirecting to dog.html (not actual name) but, the second link that I need to be opened isn't opening.

Comment: @Jelly, try it now, corected my solution ;)

Comment: Ugh, I give up ;-; I'll just do what I originally had.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<a href="dog.html" target="_blank" onclick="window.location.href ="dog.html";">Click</a>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use single quotes for `window.location.href ='dog.html'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use html without javascript for this. Try this code:

```
<a href="dog.html" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need the user to be redirected in the current tab, as well as have a link opened in another tab without losing focus on cat.html for example