# Redirect parent window when child is called

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am having a problem to redirect the parent window. I am having a function which should open an HTML page after clicking on Login in the new window (child) and the parent should redirect itself to another page.

```
function closeMe()
    {
        var winClose = window.open("closer.html","_self");
    }
```

It is called after clicking on Login.

```
  self.setTimeout("closeMe()",500);
```

Now, my problem is I don't want to close the window. But how to redirect simultaneously. I have tried `window.open`, `document.location.href` but still, I am not able to do. This occurs only in IE. Others browser don't close the window.

Can anybody help?

**edit:**

**I don't want to use**

```
  self.setTimeout("closeMe()",500);
```

But what else can I use to redirect the parent window.

The other option I tried:

- Calling the function directly (closeMe)
- window.location.href ="closer.html";
- document.location.href='closer.html
- Giving it is as a function for ex 
  `function(){document.location.href='closer.html'}`
- Adding '\' before the file name.

My code-
**This is called to redirect to a new window when Login is successful. I want to redirect the login page to close.html. Thats it.**

```
function RedirectPage(path)
{


  var intWidth = screen.width - 10; //Adjust for the end of screen    var intHeight = screen.height - 80; //Adjust for the Icon Bar at the bottom of the window.
  var strWinProp = " toolbar=no"         //Back, Forward, etc...
               + ",location=no"      //URL field
               + ",directories=no"   //"What's New", etc...
               + ",status=yes"       //Status Bar at bottom of window.
               + ",menubar=no"       //Menubar at top of window.
               + ",resizable=yes"     //Allow resizing by dragging.
               + ",scrollbars=yes"   //Displays scrollbars is document is larger than window.
               + ",titlebar=yes"     //Enable/Disable titlebar resize capability.
               + ",width="+intWidth    //Standard 640,800/788, 800/788
               + ",height="+intHeight  //Standard 480,600/541, 600/566               
               + ",top=0"              //Offset of windows top edge from screen.
               + ",left=0"             //Offset of windows left edge from screen.
               + "";  
    var win = window.open(path,'_blank',strWinProp);
    window.location.href ="closer.html";
```

[image: Please see the attached Screenshot]

Comment: You are calling a script created to close the window in IE using a hack. You do not want to close the window? Don't call the script then! The _self overwrites the opener and then in closeMe you close it. Just don't do that.

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098601/how-to-make-a-link-open-in-new-tab-as-well-as-redirect-in-current

Comment: @mplungjan  but when I calling the function it is not working

Comment: You need to post more information. Right now your question does not make sense when I look at your code. It does exactly what you instructed it to do.

Comment: Why are you calling function closeMe? It closes the window. If you need to redirect from clicking on `Login` which you also do not tell us what is - link or submit button? then you need to code a redirect instead of calling closeMe. Post more code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry you are right. It is not the function you need to call. Ever. So show login and some html too and explain what you need to happen. Redirect AND login? Close the child page?

Comment: So where do you call RedirectPage and what is in the parameter you pass it? RedirectPage("closer.html") ?

Comment: that path is different html file...that it is main page path I pass

Comment: I do not see `self.setTimeout("closeMe()",500);` in your new code

Comment: yes because I removed it as it was commented out. you will also not see all the other approaches I have tried

Comment: @ricky please read the question again...maybe I was not clear last time

Comment: Perhaps you want `opener.location="someurl"; closeMe()`

Comment: Actually, if I remove  self.setTimeout("closeMe()",500); this than what it will do is it will open the other page but login page will get stuck it will not get redirected to other pages...not dependent on what function or method I am using it will stuck for sure

Comment: You need to sketch what you need. Click what to login, open what, redirect what and close what?

Comment: Clicking on login it should open main page in new window and login should redirect to closer

Comment: @mplungjan Please see the image attached

Comment: Was LOGIN a page in the original browser window, then you cannot. If LOGIN is a popup you opened by script, then just close it. Why not use a modal dialog?

Comment: Your requirement to open main in a new window and close current window is not possible due to security and denial of service issues. Your description in your question is not conforming to your requirements- please update to reflect the steps user takes

Comment: ok...let me check on that